# issues on getting a full path from file

Tags: c#, winforms

I written the code like this in order to get the full path of a file

```
string path=Path.GetFullPath("abc.txt");
```

even i tried like this also

```
FileInfo fi=new FileInfo("abc.txt");
string path=fi.FullName;
```

Actually the abc.txt is present in

```
C:\\New folder\\abc.txt
```

But it is displaying the output like this

```
"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\AuthenticationAndAuthorization\\AuthenticationAndAuthorization\\bin\\Debug\\abc.txt"
```

what might be the problem please suggest me

Comment: How did you navigate to the file directory? Usually when you work with files you want to utilize the OpenFileDialog. What happens in your case is creating a new file and the file is created in the directory of your project. You are not opening an existing file.

Comment: i created my file at c drive in New folder sir...

Comment: In C# , the '\' is an escape character. To counteract this, C# is automatically adding the extra '\' to each existing '\' (thus creating '\\') to ensure that the pathname is correct. + if you don't specify the full path, the application is going to take the bin\debug folder per default

Comment: What Dieter B said is the case.

Comment: @Dieter B sir... It is not displaying the exact location where it is present

Comment: Because the function Path.GetFullPath("abc.txt"); is going to take the bin\debug folder by default. I would reference the path in your app.config or hardcode it in your code

Comment: Maybe give some more context. Why don't you know the full path of the file? Is user interaction an option? How is the file created? Do you need to SEARCH for the file because you don't know its path at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

Currently your exe is kept at the location which you got. So when you use Path.GetFullPath or FileInfo.Fullname. in that case it takes the relative path.

Question arises how would your application will know where is your abc.txt is kept. As it's kept at C:\New Folder..

how would your program is going to search at that location? you need to specify how it will search file at that location.

From your comment: you created the that file, how did you created that file, Share your code :)

Comment: If I a given a file name as a input then i want the output is the full path in which the file is present

Comment: if you give only filename then it would assume file in your debug location. Can you share what exactly is the motive of your program. Because there might be many abc.txt in your c drive.

Comment: imagine this case: you have 10 abc.txt files in your c drive at different different location. How would your program will know which one to choose?

Answer (score 1):

In C# , the '\' is an escape character. 
To counteract this, C# is automatically adding the extra '\' to each existing '\' (thus creating '\') to ensure that the pathname is correct.

Plus, if you don't specify the full path (add a drive like C:), the application is going to take the bin\debug folder per default

Try something in the line of:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:/New folder");
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("abc.txt");

foreach(var file in rgFiles)
{
 string path=Path.GetFullPath(file);
}
```

Comment: I don't think his problems are the \. I think he is wondering why the returned path is not C:\\New folder\\abc.txt

Comment: @sebingel I think that too, OP seems to not understand that just the file name is not enough to fully define a file you want to use, you should also provide it with its path or you will simply get a new file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this snippet to specify your file:

```
string fileName = string.Empty;    
OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{            
      fileName = openDialog.FileName;
      // do your futher processing after you have the filename
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without an actual path to your file Path.GetFullPath just kinda assumes your abc.txt is in the directory of you exe.
You can get to relative paths this way.

If your file is in C:\New folder\ you have to tell that to Path.GetFullPath.

Path.GetFullPath is not a method to search for your file. It just returns your the absolute path.